# How to Dynamically Connect to Database based on some parameters (ASP.Net Web API)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2012

I have a Web API hosted.
(ASP.Net web API, C#, IIS, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary, SQL server 2012)
The client who calls the service, wants to send some information i.e code for sites. 
For example :  "AME" for America, "IND" for India.

Based on this perticular code ("AME"/"IND"), I have to connect to respective Database server and perform CRUD operations.

What should be the design and architecture ? 
Step by step please.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: We will not solve your work! Please post something you have already tried.

Comment: Just use the different strings to construct your **ConnectionString**.

Comment: But i would suggest to have multiple context. Each for the specific database. Depending on you "AME"/"IND" you would use ContextAME or ContextIND

Comment: @Daniel first, sorry !!! for dissapointing you.
2nd Thanks for your suggestion.
I am newbee to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use factory pattern for this specific problem.

Here are a few references:

[Link 1](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern)

[Link 2](https://www.dotnetperls.com/factory)